# .net core IsInRoleAsync 'System.ObjectDisposedException'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-1.1

I warking on application using .net Core 1.1.1
I need to check if current user is a member of admin role in tag helper. The constructor of the TagHelper is

```
public MyTagHelper(UserManager<User> UserManager, IActionContextAccessor ActionContextAccessor)
    {
        userManager = UserManager;
        actionContextAccessor = ActionContextAccessor;            
    }
```

then override Process method:

```
 public override async void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
     currentUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.HttpContext.User);
        isAdmin = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(currentUser, "admin");
    }
```

if leave the string `isAdmin = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(currentUser, "admin")` uncommented I have exception: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll"

I can't understand why.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process is a synchronous method, and making it async void means it doesn't wait for your function to finish. You should instead override ProcessAsync and return a Task. Try this:

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    currentUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.HttpContext.User);
    isAdmin = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(currentUser, "admin");
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, but the best way to thank someone here is to accept their answer and upvote it. (Click the green arrow and up arrow to the left of my answer)